# Why replace the challenge by webauthn?

Tags: webauthn

The following strings are different for server-generated and client-generated challenges:

- `+` -> `-`
- `/` -> `_`
- `=` -> (empty space)

Why do we need to do substitution to solve this?

Source code used for reference.

- webauthn.io

  - https://webauthn.io/dist/js/webauthn.js
- Jxck/jxck.io

  - https://github.com/Jxck/jxck.io/blob/master/labs.jxck.io/webauthentication/fido-u2f/static/js/base64.mjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it the difference between the plain Base64 encoding and Base64 URL, and padding vs. no padding options (trailing `=`s). The latter is safe to use in URLs, contrary to the former. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#URL_applications

Webauthn requires [using Base64 URL encoding](https://www.w3.org/TR/webauthn/#dependencies) while some functions (such as javascript's `atob` or `btoa`) the plain Base64 encoding scheme, hence the need to convert from one to another.

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to mark this answer as correct ;)